# Can the Staff of the Python be used as a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

Can the D&D 5e version of the Staff of the Python be used as a weapon? If so, what are its stats?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, and it has the statistics of a quarterstaff.

According to the [Magic Item Categories](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/treasure#MagicItemCategories) listed in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (Chapter 7):

> Unless a staff's description says otherwise, a staff can be used as a quarterstaff.

Since the [staff of the python](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-python) doesn't say otherwise, it can be used as a [quarterstaff](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/quarterstaff), so it deals 1d6 bludgeoning damage and has the Versatile (d8) property. Since it is a magic item that is a weapon, it counts as a magic weapon for purposes of overcoming damage resistances and immunities.

Comment: Is it considered a magic weapon, even though it has no specific magical bonus?

Comment: It is a weapon, and it is a magic item, so it is a magic weapon.